# Strange bahaviour with lapply, lazy evaluation?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, lapply

can someone explain me what is going on here?
I have a list of lists that I need to match with a table, and I am using *lapply* with *fmatch* (package fastmatch http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastmatch/index.html) for that (which I think uses matching by hashing the table to be matched with, in contrast to *match*).
However, this is rather slow if table values have to be evaluated in the function (at least that's what I suspect), but I am not entirely sure.
I have found a workaround which speeds up the computation from 5.5 to 0.01s, but would like a more elegant solution.
Here is a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(10)

matchFeatures <- replicate(n = 1000, paste0("a", sample(x = 1:10000, size = sample(x = 1:10, size = 1))))
matchTable <- 1:10000

system.time(m1 <- lapply(matchFeatures, function(features) fmatch(features, paste0("a", 1:10000))))
system.time(m2 <- lapply(matchFeatures, function(features) force(fmatch(features, paste0("a", 1:10000)))))
system.time({tempTable <- paste0("a", 1:10000); m3 <- lapply(matchFeatures, function(features) fmatch(features, tempTable))})
identical(m1, m3)
```

Thanks Justin, just to follow up, I was looking for something like this:

```
system.time(m4 <- lapply(matchFeatures, fmatch, table = paste0("a", 1:10000)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first two functions, you're running the `paste` command once for each iteration (i.e. 10000 times).  In the third, it only happens once.  If you use `matchTable <- paste('a', 1:10000)` and pass `matchTable` to all three versions you get a substantial speed up as expected.

```
matchFeatures <- replicate(n = 1000, 
                           paste0("a", 
                           sample(x = 1:10000, 
                                  size = sample(x = 1:10, size = 1))))
matchTable <- paste('a', 1:10000)

system.time(m1 <- lapply(matchFeatures, 
                         function(features) fmatch(features, matchTable)))
system.time(m2 <- lapply(matchFeatures, 
                         function(features) force(fmatch(features, matchTable))))
system.time(m3 <- lapply(matchFeatures, 
                         function(features) fmatch(features, matchTable)))
identical(m1, m3)
```